# Open & Control FireFox (Partially completed)

Tags: firefox, vbscript

I have the following VBScript, which I found online. It successfully opens Firefox, selects whatever profile I want and automatically navigates to a URL of my choosing.

The only thing I want it to do is automatically display the developer tools (more specifically, the Network Monitor if possible). Is there any code that can be added to this to achieve what is needed? I'm not sure if a send keys command could also do the trick, to activate the shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)?

```
Dim wshshell

Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

FirefoxProfile = "default"
FirefoxPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
webappurl = "https://www.google.com"
Height = "700"
Width = "920"
Status ="0"
Toolbar = "0"
Menubar = "0"

Set wshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wshshell.Run qq(FirefoxPath) & " -P " & qq(FirefoxProfile) _
  & " -status " & qq(status) & " -Toolbar " & qq(toolbar) _
  & " -menubar " & qq(menubar) & " -Height " & qq(Height) _
  & " -Width " & qq(Width) & " " & webappurl

Set wshshell = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't expose a COM object, so you don't get much control over it from VBScript. Using [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is about the best you can do without third party tools like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). Make sure to [activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) the application window first, so the keystrokes don't go wherever.

```
wshshell.Run qq(FirefoxPath) & ...
wshshell.AppActivate "your page title"
wshshell.SendKeys "^+q"   '"^Q" (with an uppercase Q) would work too
```

Note that `SendKeys` tends to be rather flaky, because the keystrokes always go to the active window, whatever that is at the moment, so this approach is not recommended in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SendKeys but that part would look like this:

```
WshShell.AppActivate "your name - Google Chrome"
WshShell.SendKeys "^+{Q}"
```

Yeah, it's good.